# C# Linq OrderBy Object.ID && Object.SortedList.Key.Value

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, sortedlist

I'm having headache trying to filter a List, and can't find answer on the web. To be honest, I don't even know if it's possible to achieve, but I guess it should be.

So, MyItem class looks like this :

```
public class MyItem
{
     private int _ID1, _ID2, _registeredTime;
     private SortedList<DateTime, AnotherItem> _mySortedList;
     public int ID1
     {
          get { return _ID1; }
          set { _ID1 = value; }
     }
     public int ID2
     {
          get { return _ID2; }
          set { _ID2 = value; }
     }
     public int RegisteredTime
     {
          get { return _registeredTime; }
          set { _registeredTime = value; }
     }
     public SortedList<DateTime, AnotherItem> MySortedList
     {
          get { return _mySortedList; }
          set { _mySortedList = value; }
     }
}
```

My goal is to only get the first occurrence of each pair (ID1, ID2) based on RegisteredTime, so I'm using the code below and it works like a charm :

```
BaseList = ItemsList.OrderBy(x => x.RegisteredTime).ToList();
FilteredList = new List<MyItem>(BaseList.GroupBy(x => new { x.ID1, x.ID2 })
                                        .Select(x => x.First())).ToList());
```

But another constraint makes me need to get a list based on first pair (ID1, ID2) + MySortedList.Key, so I could get something like :

```
ID1, ID2, MySortedList[Date1]
ID1, ID2, MySortedList[Date2]
```

So I'd like to have a request that does :

```
FilteredList = BaseList.GroupBy(x => new { x.ID1, x.ID2, x.MySortedList."UniqueKey" })
                       .Select(x => x.First()))
                       .ToList();
```

But I can't find a solution to achieve this. I'm kinda new to Linq and don't know how this kind of particularity works (and, as I said before, if it's even possible).

Thanks for your help !

Comment: First thing to change - all your properties could be massively simplified using automatically implemented properties, e.g. `public int ID1 { get; set; }`. That'll make a [mcve] easier to write.

Comment: Where did `Date1` and `Date2` come from? What is `MySortedList.Key`?

Answer (score 1):

First group the items by the keys, order items of each group by the `RegisteredTime` and finally retrieve only the first in each group:

```
var result = BaseList.GroupBy(x => new { x.ID1, x.ID2, x.MySortedList[yourKey]})
                     .Select(g => g.OrderBy(i => i.RegisteredTime).First());
```

Notice that if you try to group by a key that is not present in collection you will get the following exception: `"The given key was not present in the dictionary."` To cope with that scenario use `TryGetValue` and determine what you want to do with items that do not have that key.

In addition instead of explicitly implementing the properties, as they all use the default implementation use auto-property:

```
public class MyItem
{
     public int ID1 { get; set; }
     public int ID2 { get; set; }
     public int RegisteredTime { get; set; }
     public SortedList<DateTime, AnotherItem> MySortedList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `MySortedList` is a member of `MyItem` so in your query you should have `x.MySortedList`.

Comment: @NetMage - you are right. Thanks. Forgot to type. Added.